# ImageResizer.MVC not working on share hosting

Tags: asp.net-mvc, imageresizer

I am using the [ImageResizer.MVC](http://nuget.org/packages/ImageResizer.Mvc/) package in my solution. It is working 100% when I deploy it to my local IIS server. But as soon as I deploy to my live site (shared hosting) the images are not resized as expected.

Are there any known issues or common pitfalls that I need to be aware of when using this package with shared hosting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

#### Sounds like your shared hosting is running in Classic Mode

[The documentation explains how to configure IIS so ImageResizer can affect image requests](http://imageresizing.net/docs/install/classicmode).

Comment: Jip, that was the issue, got them to change it and it works now. I can't see the IIS config the hosting company uses, so it was a bit of a guessing game